Configure Ubuntu to create only one IPv6 address, without the "noprefixroute" flag
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS comes up with two IPv6 addresses; one appears to be always the same, and has the "noprefixroute" flag and is therefore not accessible from the outside world; the other is the temporary address, which is different on each boot-up.  Unfortunately my router (BT Smarthub) most often creates a pinhole for the first address.  This is useless.  I need a working pinhole for use (occasionally) by certbot.
Is there any way to configure Ubuntu to create only the temporary, externally routable address?
Dynamic DNS, updated on each boot-up, takes care of the changing address, so I don't need a static IPv6 address.
